# Counting word in cell/column base on number at that word

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please, allow me ask a question about formula of counting word base on last number follow that word.

example:

```
  | A           | B
--------------------
1 | thumbnail20 | 20
2 | gallery13   | 13
3 | girl45      | 45
```

I'm so appreciate for all answer, sorry for duplicate question

> thanks for @ziganotschka and @BHAWANI SINGH, it's all work, case close :)

Comment: so `B` column is *output* and `A` is *input*

Comment: yup A is input and B is output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are several options depending on your data structure, e.g.

- `=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^[:digit:]]", ""))`

will extract all digits from the A column to the B column

- Should you have several numbers within your string,

`` =SPLIT(lower(A4),"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm`-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()") ``

will extract the first number into column B, the second into column C etc.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to extract only the digits to the right, then** 
`=arrayformula(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)+1-min(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))))`